# mysql order by field order doesn't meet my expectations

Tags: mysql

I want to order my SQL output using the FIELD argument but when I do, it first spits out the results I don't want then it spits out the results I want first. Above the results it first spits out. If that makes any sense ;)

How do I spit out the defined values first then the rest?

SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_specs` WHERE itemid = '$id' ORDER BY FIELD(spec_type, 'value 1', 'value 2');
```

Current output:

```
Value 5 
Value 6

Value 1
Value 2
```

Wanted output:

```
Value 1
Value 2 

Value 5
Value 6
```

I know about the case argument but I don't want to use it since it's not as easy to update.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause, to convert `0` (not found) to `999` (after all values), as in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `product_specs` 
WHERE itemid = '$id' 
ORDER BY case 
  when FIELD(spec_type, 'value 1', 'value 2') = 0 then 999
  else FIELD(spec_type, 'value 1', 'value 2') end
```

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to sort the values? repeating the same "array" in the query seems like a "whatever it works" solution. no offense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Niels You can always use math tricks to convert a `0` into a big number. However, the computational cost of computing the expression `FIELD(spec_type, 'value 1', 'value 2')` twice is negligible.

Comment: Alright for now it works, I put everything in a variable so I don't have to write the same values twice.